# Image.FromStream throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net

I get an OutOfMemoryException on the same method randomly when I call the next code:

```
private byte[] RotateImage(byte[] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
            return null;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array))
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
            {
                //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
                using (var rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height))
                {
                    rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
                    //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.TranslateTransform((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2);
                        //rotate the image
                        g.RotateTransform(180);
                        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)image.Width / 2, -(float)image.Height / 2);
                        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
                        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
                        g.Save();
                    }

                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        rotatedBmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        return stream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Production server has 48gb of RAM... almost 40gb free.
I added a few lines to call the garbagecollection explicitly but it still happening.

Comment: How big is the image? Is your process 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Have you checked if it is the same image file it "randomly" fails on?

Comment: What version of .Net? This is was a known issue with the garbage collector on some older versions of .Net Framework, where it would run out of _address space_ (not actual memory) because it never or rarely compacted the process's memory space, even though actual memory in use was fine. I understand newer versions of .Net Core have improved the siutation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing IIS process from 32bit to 64bit.